# Setting style by object #id in PyQt5

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6

I have 2 files in my project:
**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication)
from styles import styles

class MyApp(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.setStyleSheet(styles)
    btn1 = QPushButton('Button1', self)
    btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())
    btn1.move(50, 50)
    btn2 = QPushButton('Button2', self)
    btn2.resize(btn2.sizeHint())
    btn2.move(100, 100)
    self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and **styles.py**:

```
styles="QPushButton#btn2 { background-color: red }"
```

As stated [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) this one should change the background color of the btn2. However, it does nothing. What's wrong?

```
styles="QPushButton { background-color: red }"
```

works fine (for all instances of QPushButton class). I'm working with PyQt5 and Python 3.5

Comment: There is no object with that id in your code. In fact, none of the objects in your code has an id.

Answer (score 11):

OK, that's how it works: I firstly have to set the name of the object I want to reference in the stylesheet.
Like:

```
self.btn2.setObjectName('btn2')
```

After this

```
styles="QPushButton#btn2 { background-color: red }"
```

worked OK.